# issue removing a XDocument node based on its attribute

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to remove a `CreditCard` node in a `XDocument` called `doc` based on its `name` attribute but its not working as intended.

`doc` is my `XDocument` and it looks like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XComment("XML test file"),
                new XElement("CreditCards",
                    new XElement("CreditCard",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "TestCard1"),
                        new XAttribute("phoneNumber", 121212142121)),
                    new XElement("CreditCard",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "TestCard2"),
                        new XAttribute("phoneNumber", 6541465561)),
                    new XElement("CreditCard",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "TestCard3"),
                        new XAttribute("phoneNumber", 445588))
                )
            );
```

This is the query I try to run but it doesn't remove the node. `name` is a string I pass to this function as a reference to tell it what to delete

```
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("CreditCards")
                        let attr = node.Attribute("name")
                        where attr != null && attr.Value == name
                        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

I don't get any errors with this, but nothing is deleted either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking for "**CreditCards**" with a name, not "**CreditCard**".

Try the following;

```
doc.Descendants("CreditCard")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == name)
   .Remove();
```

Comment: my bad the XDocument is wrong i edited it to represent what im working with now. this was the old version. i replaced the elements within CreditCard with attributes

Comment: Its working i just changed Element to Attribute and your answer is working. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have lowercase name of attribute in your query `name`. But in your xml name of attribute is `Name`. Xml is case sensitive. Also attribute `Name` is a child of `CreditCard` element, not of `CreditCards` elements:

```
doc.Descendants("CreditCards")
   .Elements()
   .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("Name") == name) 
   .Remove();
```