# C# linq XDoc Remove child node based on duplicate xelement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XDocument:

```
<GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
  <GetAssetWarrantyResult>
    <Faults />
    <Response>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>UI002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>OPTI 3020,TIGRISSFFFBTX</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>aaaaaa</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>1234567</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>422-0052</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>984-0092</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>939-7358</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2015-03-22T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2015-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>939-6868</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>421-9982</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>525-0013</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>422-0008</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>7M002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>POWEREDGE R720XD, ORCA S PE</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>1846</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>8523145</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>936-7263</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>SV</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Silver Premium Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>8</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>983-6402</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>936-7243</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2014-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>989-2701</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
</GetAssetWarrantyResult>
```

What I am trying to do is remove each `Warranty` Node within the `Warranties` Node that has the duplicate `XElement` of `ServiceLevelDescription`.

Example of section I am trying to edit:

```
<Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>422-0052</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>984-0092</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>939-7358</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2015-03-22T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>          
        </Warranties>
```

I have tried several variations of:

```
XDocument testing = XDocument.Load(testXMLPath);
testing.Root.Element("Response").Descendants("Warranty")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ServiceLevelDescription") == (string)x.Element("ServiceLevelDescription"))
                .Remove();
```

and:

```
var testRemoval = from warranties in testing.Descendants("Request")
                              from warranty in warranties.Descendants()
                              group warranties by warranty.Attribute("Warranty").Value into distinctResult
                              select new
                              {
                                  warr = distinctResult.FirstOrDefault().Attribute("ServiceLevelDescription").Value, value = distinctResult.Key
                              };
```

Sadly, this does not work.

I have tried: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887292/c-sharp-linq-xml-query-where-multiple-elements-of-same-name-from-a-parent-node-b) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612393/issue-removing-a-xdocument-node-based-on-its-attribute) - These are the two closest things to what I am trying to accomplish

Clarification: I am just wanting to remove the duplicate (`Warranty`) nodes based on if the `ServiceLevelDescription` field is a duplicated within the `Warranties` parent Node.

Note: This XML comes from a steam. Maybe I can filter it when it comes in

**UPDATE:** I decided to try and approach this from another angle. Maybe if I try and recreate the xml with the desired information this will work.

This is what I have so far:

```
    var newDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Machine", xlBaseInfo.Select(z =>
        new XElement("Asset",
            new XElement("Product", z.Product),
            new XElement("OrderNumber", z.OrderNumber),
            new XElement("ServiceTag", z.ServiceTag),
            new XElement("ShipDate", z.ShipDate),
                (new XElement("Warranties", testing.Select(x =>
                    new XElement("Warranty",                        
                        new XElement("Service",
                        new XElement("ServiceDescription", x.Service),
                        new XElement("Provider", x.Provider),
                        new XElement("StartDate", x.StartDate),
                        new XElement("EndDate", x.EndDate),
                        new XElement("Type", x.TypeOfWarranty)
            )))
            //Get unique results here .FirstOrDefualt Does not work
            ))))));
```

**UPDATE 2:** I found this, and looks promising:

```
// Return a list of duplicate nodes
            var findDups = from n in testing.Root.Descendants("Warranties")
                           group n by n.Attribute("ServiceLevelDescription").Value into warrantyGroup
                           where warrantyGroup.Count() > 1
                           from eg in warrantyGroup
                           where eg.Attribute("ServiceLevelDescription").Value != "0" //TODO: <--- Condition to check for duplicates
                           select eg;

            // Remove the duplicate nodes
            foreach (XElement element in findDups)
            {
                element.Remove();
            }
```

OR:

```
XDocument groupTest = XDocument.Load(testXMLPath);

            groupTest.Root.Elements("Warranties")
                .SelectMany(s => s.Elements("Warranty")
                .GroupBy(g => g.Attribute("ServiceLevelDescription").Value)
                .SelectMany(m => m.Skip(1))).Remove();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the remove based on ServiceLevelDescription which a text? It much more clear to use the ItemNumber as the key ?

Comment: Item Number is not unique to the ServiceLevelDescription. However the ServiceLevelCode might be unique and could possibly be used to check for duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to say initially that the overall design looks flawed if you are having to do this sort of filtering. In saying that, I am not sure of the context of what you are doing, so here is a solution regardless.

This should work.

```
document.Root.DescendantsAndSelf("Warranties")
    .SelectMany(n =>
        n.Elements("Warranty")
            .GroupBy(g => g.Element("ServiceLevelDescription").Value)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g => g))
    .Remove();
```

Here's a breakdown of what is going on, in the order of the query execution above. Ask away if you cannot follow along.

1. Finding every `<Warranties />` node and its children,
2. Grouping the `<Warranty />` children in each `<Warranties />` node by the `<ServiceLevelDescription />`,
3. Discarding any unique nodes and only keeping duplicates
4. Flattening out the incredibly nested lists of XElements into one IEnumerable, on which it executes the .Remove().

I fetch the `<Warranties />` nodes instead of the `<Warranty />` nodes initially because I want to keep each set of `<Warranty />` nodes grouped together to remove duplicates from ONLY its parent `<Warranties />` node.

Here is the output from the original input:

```
<GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
  <GetAssetWarrantyResult>
    <Faults />
    <Response>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>UI002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>OPTI 3020,TIGRISSFFFBTX</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>aaaaaa</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>1234567</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>984-0092</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>7M002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>POWEREDGE R720XD, ORCA S PE</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>1846</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>8523145</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>936-7263</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>SV</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Silver Premium Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>8</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>983-6402</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
    </Response>
  </GetAssetWarrantyResult>
</GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
```

Is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like traversing document and removing all the double, I guess you can write  a sub-query in linq not to use for each

```
 var info=testing.Root.Element("Response").Descendants("Warranty");
    foreach (var qry in info)
    {
        if(qry.Slect(x => (string)x.Element("ServiceLevelDescription")).Count()>1)
        {
             qry.Remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this will just check for the count and not for duplicates.

Comment: I thought that want you wanted I guess not